# Kendo UI grid drag&drop placeholder

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have grid with drag&drop functionality:

```
var data = [
    { id: 1, text: "text 1", position: 0 },
    { id: 2, text: "text 2", position: 1 },
    { id: 3, text: "text 3", position: 2 }
]

var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        data: data,        
        schema: {
            model: {
                id: "id",
                fields: {
                    id: { type: "number" },
                    text: { type: "string" },
                    position: { type: "number" }
                }
            }
        }
    });

var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,  
    scrollable: false,    
    columns: ["id", "text", "position"]            
}).data("kendoGrid");

grid.table.kendoDraggable({
    filter: "tbody > tr",
    group: "gridGroup",
    threshold: 100,
    hint: function(e) {
        return $('<div class="k-grid k-widget"><table><tbody><tr>' + e.html() + '</tr></tbody></table></div>');
    }
});

grid.table.kendoDropTarget({
    group: "gridGroup",
    drop: function(e) {        
        e.draggable.hint.hide();
        var target = dataSource.getByUid($(e.draggable.currentTarget).data("uid")),
            dest = $(document.elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY));

        if (dest.is("th")) {
            return;
        }       
        dest = dataSource.getByUid(dest.parent().data("uid"));

        //not on same item
        if (target.get("id") !== dest.get("id")) {
            //reorder the items
            var tmp = target.get("position");
            target.set("position", dest.get("position"));
            dest.set("position", tmp);

            dataSource.sort({ field: "position", dir: "asc" });
        }                
    }
});
```

(working example: http://jsfiddle.net/JBeQn/ )

Is it possible to show the placeholder where the row will be dropped? From current implementation it's not obvious. So I would like to make something like this:
http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/events

or this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bgrins/tzYbU/

In the demo above placeholder is showed and it's quite easy to understand where the row will be dropped.

So any ideas?